# Division overflow using pow()

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, numbers, double

```
Q = (a_i + b_i) / (2^s)
-10^10 ≤ s ≤ 10^10
1 ≤ a_i, b_i ≤ 10^9

It is guaranteed that -10^10 ≤ Q ≤  10^10.

Here s,a_i,b_i are integers and Q is a decimal no.
```

When we calculate Q, there is overflow due to large value of 2^s.I am using pow(2,s) to calculate 2^s. How can i calculate Q,given the range of Q as in the statement.

Comment: I would take the log of the numerator and of the denominator separately.  If you do this log base 2, then the log of the denominator is just s.  Division of numbers can be done by subtraction of their logs.

Comment: Please show your actual code, explain, how you realized, you get an overflow and for what values of a_i, b_i and s you do.

Comment: It shoudn't overflow for values of `Q` in that range: could you give an example of some numbers?

Comment: 2^(10^10) will not be even nearly representable in any common floating point format. `long double` on x86 and other platforms that support 80 or 128 bit extended floating point numbers has a decimal exponent of 2^16384, which is 2^(10^5) approximately. Anything beyond that is not representable by standard floating point formats. My suggestion would be to flush values outside some range of `s` to either `0` (too small) or infinity (too large) - but if you need to do further math on `Q` from that.

Comment: s = -10^10 => Q > 2^(10^10) (except trivial case when a_i and b_i are both zero) so the problem does not seem well posed to me...  I'd say roughly that -34 <= s so that abs(Q) <= 10^10

Answer (score 0):

I assume by your statement that `Q` is decimal, that this involves floating point operations rather than integer arithmetic.

If you can't use logarithms for some reason, the slower approach would be to calculate a floating point value with value equal to `a_i + b_i`.    If `s` is positive, simply divide that value `s` times by `2` (in a loop).    If `s` is negative, multiply instead of divide.

For arbitrary `a_i` and `b_i`, you will still have the risk of overflow (when `s` is negative) or underflow (`s` positive) and will need to manage that.   However, you claim to have a guarantee that is not the case .....

Comment: So does multiplying/dividing a number by two up to 10^10 times prevent the result from over-/underflowing? Aside from taking up a lot more time, I don't see how this helps solve the problem at all.

Comment: The OP has claimed a guarantee range of `a_i` and `b_i` which is sufficient to prevent the calculation of `a_i + b_i` from overflowing.  The OP also claimed a guarantee that the value of `Q` will not overflow.   That means the only part of the calculation potentially involving overflow is due to calling `pow(2,s)` for some values of `s`.   Breaking that calculation into smaller parts, and repeatedly dividing/multiplying by `2` is one way to avoid computing that large intermediate value, and will not overflow because of constraints stated by the OP.   It is a basic trick of numeric analysis.